# call model from a child directory

Tags: django, model, import, parent

I can't import my model "LogDBEvents" from my "core" application... Here is the hierarchy of my project:

```
1/var/www/arpaso (root of the project)
    2/core
        3/signals
            4/__init__.py
            4/log_db_event.py
        3/__init__.py
        3/models.py
    2/manage.py
```

It might be a circular reference, as I have read in other posts:

```
 File "/var/www/arpaso/core/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from core.signals.log_db_event import save_handler, del_handler
  File "/var/www/arpaso/core/signals/log_db_event.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core.models import LogDBEvents
ImportError: cannot import name LogDBEvents
```

If so, how to fix it? Here are my two files:

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from core.signals.log_db_event import save_handler, del_handler
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete

#Q10 create model to store database events
class LogDBEvents(models.Model):
    EVENTS= (
        ('DC','Database entry created'),
        ('DD','Database entry deleted'),
        ('DE','Database entry edited'),
    )
    event_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    event_type = models.CharField(choices=EVENTS, max_length=2)
    info = models.TextField()


#start a listener for INSERT INTO or UPDATE queries
post_save.connect(save_handler, dispatch_uid='post_save')
#start a listener for DELETE queries
post_delete.connect(del_handler, dispatch_uid='post_delete')
```

**log_db_event.py:**

```
from core.models import LogDBEvents


#Q10: saves a signal into the database
def log_handler (signal_type, sender, **kwargs):
    #do not save events from LogDBEvents (otherwise unfinite calls!)
    if sender != LogDBEvents:
        LogDBEvents(event_type=signal_type,
                info="%s model changed with new entry %s"%(
                        sender.__name__,
                        kwargs['instance'])
        ).save()

#Q10: a create or add signal is intercepted
def save_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        return log_handler ('DC', sender, **kwargs)
    else:
        return log_handler ('DE', sender, **kwargs)

#Q10: a delete signal is intercepted
def del_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    return log_handler ('DD', sender, **kwargs)
```

Comment: in your `models.py` you import `save_handler` and `del_handler` and in  `log_db_event.py` you import `LogDBEvents` which is a circular reference.

Comment: In log_db_event.py, when I import LogDBEvents, I import only the class LogDBEvents, not the imports of the file, right?

Comment: In order to import something from within the file, Python has to search the whole file, meaning that it has to evaluate everything within the file hence circular reference.

Comment: Ok I understand now, thanks. What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to handle this. StackOverflow has a lot of questions with similar problem. You can see what methods might suit you best. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+circular+reference

Comment: Ok thanks, so I'll stick to my solution. Not sure it's the best, but it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this method:

**log_db_event.py:**

```
import core.models
instance=core.models.LogDBEvents()
```

It works ;).